# Receiving updates from API every second

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

An Angular RxJS code makes an API call to get information from an API service
However, I need the request to be made every second. I understand that I need to use Observables but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: FYI: You can use an object for forkJoin instead of an array so you don't have to map it in the pipe

Answer (score 2):

You can use rxjs [interval](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/interval) operator for polling.

Comment: @Drenai You are right: I try to think about it. What also comes to my mind is to repeat the calls wrapped in forkjoin. But that does not fulfill the 1s requirement.

Comment: FYI, `timer(0, 1000)` will start immediately.

Answer (score 1):

This approach should work well (in pseudo code)

```js
interval
   pipe(
     exhaustMap 
        forkJoin
   )
```

Note: the `exhaustMap` will ignore the `interval` event if the `forkJoin` takes longer than 1s, and then it will continue every 1s

Answer (score 1):

You can use `interval()` to ping the server every `x` milliseconds. You can the do the `forkJoin()` in the `pipe()` within an `exhaustMap()`.

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ExampleService {
  private readonly INTERVAL = 1000;

  constructor(private readonly _http: HttpClient) {}

  getInformation$(id: number): Observable<publicInformation> {
    return timer(0, this.INTERVAL).pipe(
      exhaustMap(() =>
        forkJoin({
          name: this._http.get<name>(`api/name/${id}`),
          currentInformation: this._http.get<CurrentInformations>(
            `api/currentInformation/${id}`
          ),
        })
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Subscribe to the component's Observable like this:
**Note:** You could have used an array too, this example just uses two different properties.

```html
<div *ngIf="information1$ | async as data">
  <p>Name: {{ data.name.first }} {{ data.name.last }}</p>
  <p>
    {{ data.name.first }}'s Current Time: {{ data.currentInformation.current }}
  </p>
</div>

<hr />

<div *ngIf="information2$ | async as data">
  <p>Name: {{ data.name.first }} {{ data.name.last }}</p>
  <p>
    {{ data.name.first }}'s Current Time: {{ data.currentInformation.current }}
  </p>
</div>
```

The component:

```js
export class AppComponent {

  information1$ = this.exampleService.getInformation$(123);
  information2$ = this.exampleService.getInformation$(456);

  constructor(private exampleService: ExampleService) {}
}
```

[Here is a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-interval-subscription?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Note:** See the [intercept service](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-interval-subscription?file=src%2Fapp%2Fintercept.service.ts) to see how the dummy network api works. This isn't needed if an actual API exists.

Comment: If an API call was delayed and took 5s the concatMap could store up 5 pending events, which will then emit as soon as possible (ignoring the 1s polling time)